# Are there any hidden tools in tvOS for Focus Engine debugging?

Tags: debugging, tvos

One of my favorite hidden debugging tools for iOS is using `recursiveDescription` on `UIView` instances.  This is very useful for troubleshooting view locations that may be off-screen, for example.  Debugging the Focus Engine on tvOS brings its own set of challenges, especially around what it thinks are focusable elements.

**Are there any hidden debugging tools for tvOS to introspect what is going on inside the Focus Engine?**

Comment: Check https://github.com/NikKovIos/TvOS-Debug-Hints

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two helpful methods, both of which are actually documented in the [App Programming Guide for tvOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html).

### UIView

If you're trying to move focus to a particular view and can't, there's a debugging method on `UIView` that can help explain why: `_whyIsThisViewNotFocusable`

The output from this method looks something like this:

```
(lldb) po [(UIView *)0x148db5234 _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable]
ISSUE: This view has userInteractionEnabled set to NO. Views must allow user interaction to be focusable.
ISSUE: This view returns NO from -canBecomeFocused.
```

### UIFocusUpdateContext

The `UIFocusUpdateContext` object supports Xcode's QuickLook feature, so if you're paused in the debugger you can press spacebar (or click the eyeball icon next to the variable) to see a graphical representation of what the focus engine sees (image is from Apple's documentation):

[image: QuickLook example of focus update context]

Comment: And in swift 3: po myView.perform(Selector("_whyIsThisViewNotFocusable")).takeUnretainedValue()

Answer (score 4):

Since tvOS 11, troubleshooting unreachable items got a lot easier, just add this to the viewDidLoad of the ViewController in Question:

```
 if #available(tvOS 11.0, *) {
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: NSNotification.Name.UIFocusMovementDidFail
  ) { [weak self] notification in
    let context = notification.userInfo![UIFocusUpdateContextKey] as! UIFocusUpdateContext
    print(context) // If you add a breakpoint here you can quicklook the context in the debugger for more information
    print(UIFocusDebugger.checkFocusability(for: self!.collectionView)) // replace collectionView with the view you want to check
  }
}
```

This results in debug output like:

```
<UIFocusUpdateContext: 0x6080000fe800: previouslyFocusedItem=<UIKeyboard 0x7fc597d75610>, nextFocusedItem=(null), focusHeading=Down>

The following issues were found that would prevent this item from being focusable:
- ISSUE: The item is being visually occluded by the following items:
<UIView 0x7fc597c3a9e0>
```