# tvOS: Setting focus order

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, tvos

I currently have 3 objects called MenuButton that's a child of UIButton. These are defined in a row as shown in the image.

[image]

I've defined the highlight states in my MenuButton -didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator method:

```
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context
       withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    if (context.nextFocusedView == self)
    {
        [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else if (context.previouslyFocusedView == self)
    {
        [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:25.0/255.0
                                              green:23.0/255.0
                                               blue:16.0/255.0
                                              alpha:1.0]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

I've also set canBecomeFocused in the MenuButton object via:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFocused
{
    return YES;
}
```

I've set my initial focus button using:

```
[_camerasButton setNeedsFocusUpdate]
```

When I swipe right on the Simulator remote, I'm not able to get it to focus on Deliveries.

Can someone please explain how I can use UIFocusGuide to implement this correctly in Objective-C?

**UPDATE 1**
Based on JustinVoss' suggestion on the first comment, I set  breakpoint and did a _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable on the debug console. Received this hint:

```
(lldb) po [(UIView*)0x7ff68054f7c0 _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable] 
ISSUE: This view may not be focusable because other views or focus guides are occluding it.
```

I'm defining my MenuButton frames as shown:

```
MenuButton *deliveriesButton = [MenuButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [deliveriesButton setTitle:@"Deliveries" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deliveriesButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:25.0/255.0
                                                 green:23.0/255.0
                                                  blue:16.0/255.0
                                                 alpha:1.0]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deliveriesButton.titleLabel setFont:[Constants lightFontOfSize:39]];
    [deliveriesButton sizeToFit];

    deliveriesButton.center = CGPointMake(viewWidth/2,
                                       menuBarHeight / 2);

    [self.view addSubview:deliveriesButton];
    _deliveriesButton = deliveriesButton;
```

Comment: Have you tried the various focus debugging techniques? A focus guide can help if the reason focus isn't moving is because the frames of the two views aren't aligned well, but that doesn't seem to be your problem here. You may want to try the _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable method to find out why "Deliveries" can't be focused. (see my answer here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32831091/5616)

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for the answer. I set a breakpoint and did a _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable on the logoutButton and received this hint: "ISSUE: This view may not be focusable because other views or focus guides are occluding it.". Any suggestions?

Comment: There must be another view (possibly transparent) that's sitting on top of your buttons, which is causing the focus engine to not "see" your buttons. Check your view hierarchy and see if there's anything in the area that might be blocking your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution referenced by Justin Voss in the comments above, I went through the UIViews in my UIViewController and set:

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

on any view that I did not need to have a selection on (including background UIImageView objects). This resolved the problem.

Hope this helps someone else